# Most frequent words required while foreign travel

Tags: international-travel, languages, language-barrier, communication

1. Which are most important words required while visiting countries having a different language understood by you?
2. How do you manage a situation where you need to explain other person not understanding your language ?

Example:
A Japanese on a holiday trip to India, what are the minimum words required for him/her to enjoy his trip? e.g He would like to ask following in Hindi... "Where is Tajmahal" ? So he should say "Tajmahal" kahan hai ?

Comment: Hi PowerPC, as this question stands, it's overly broad as its asking for a complete phrasebook. The phrases that you'd need to know for a country would depend on the context. Phrasebook sections in most guidebooks would be a good starting point for this kind of information.

Answer (score 2):

The most useful object I use to communicate with people is a pen and a notebook. This is perfect to sketch what you are trying to say, to write numbers, bus numbers, times and dates, and to draw maps.